# Removing files interactively with find and xargs

Tags: shell, xargs, rm

I'm trying to pipe some files from the find command to the interactive remove command, so that I can double check the files I'm removing, but I've run into some trouble.

```
find -name '#*#' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -i
```

I thought the above would work, but instead I just get a string of `"rm: remove regular file ./some/path/#someFile.js#? rm: remove regular file ./another/path/#anotherFile#?..."`

Can someone explain to me what's exactly is happening, and what I can do to get my desired results? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Can someone explain to me what's exactly is happening,*

As the [man page for xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) says (under the `-a` option): "If you use this option, stdin remains unchanged **when commands are run**.
Otherwise, **stdin is redirected from /dev/null**."

Since you're not using the `-a` option, each `rm -i` command that `xargs` is running gets its stdin from /dev/null (i.e. no input is available). When `rm` asks whether to remove a particular file, the answer is effectively "no" because /dev/null gives no reply. `rm` receives an EOF on its input, so it does not remove that file, and goes on to the next file.

> *and what I can do to get my desired results?*

Besides using `find -exec` as unxnut explained, another way to do it is to use the `-o` (or `--open-tty`) option with `xargs`:

```
find -name '#*#' -print0 | xargs -0 -o rm -i
```

That's probably the ideal way, because it allows `rm -i` to handle interactive confirmation itself, as designed.

Another way is to use the `-p` (or `--interactive`) option with `xargs`:

```
find -name '#*#' -print0 | xargs -0 -p rm
```

With this approach, `xargs` handles the interactive confirmation instead of having `rm` do it. You may also want to use `-n 1`, so that each prompt only asks about one file:

```
find -name '#*#' -print0 | xargs -0 -p -n 1 rm
```

The advantage of using `xargs` over `find -exec` is that you can use it with any command that generates the file path arguments, not just with `find`.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this by using `exec` option with `find`.  Use the command

```
find . -name '#*#' -exec rm -i {} \;
```

`xargs` will not work (unless you use options such as `-o` or `-p`) because it uses `stdin` to build commands.  Since `stdin` is already in use, you cannot input the response for query with `rm`.

Comment: More detail: If `xargs` is reading items from `stdin` (i.e. if it's not using `-a` to read items from a file), then it redirects `stdin` from `/dev/null` for each command. So the prompt asking for confirmation cannot be answered by the user. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Comment: You should be using -ok: `find -name '#*#' -ok rm {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple command to solve your problem.

```sh
find . -name '#*#' -delete
```