# Removing files with rm using find and xargs

Tags: linux, xargs, rm

When I do

```
rm file.txt
```

or

```
rm *.txt
```

I'm prompted for each file, since I didn't specify the `-f` option to `rm`.

But when I do this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs rm
```

the files are removed without the confirmation.

What is the logics behind this? Is it possible to find the reason in some documentation? I cannot explain why this would be the case.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is that of 'rm -i'. Do you have an alias set in you shell for the rm command? Does 'alias rm' give any output?

Comment: `alias rm` gives the output `rm -i`, so that explains it. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have an alias set for the rm command to 'rm -i'. Therefore if you invoke the command directly as in

```
rm file.txt
```

or

```
rm *.txt
```

the alias will be expanded. If you will call it with xargs as in

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs rm
```

The rm is passed as a simple string argument to xargs and is later invoked by xargs without alias substitution of the shell.
You alias is probably defined in ~/.bashrc, in case you want to remove it.

Comment: This relies on spaces in file names... careful. Use print0 instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119953/370238

Comment: DON"T USE COMMANDS FROM THIS ANSWER. This commands are unsafe for space containing filenames. Use `find -exec`

Comment: For example, if you have two files (`config file.txt` and `config`) then `find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs rm` will delete `config` file but not `config file.txt` file.

Answer (score 26):

you can use this simple command to solve your problem

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -delete
```

Comment: Nice, but there's a typo, it should be `-type`, not `--type`, otherwise this solution worked well for me

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of xargs you may have the --no-run-if-empty GNU extension option available to you:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs  --no-run-if-empty  rm -rf
```

Comment: I know the question is about Linux, but if you are a Mac user like me, this option is implicit and is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

You want to remove into PATH_DIR1 existing files in PATH_DIR2 :

```
find PATH_DIR1 -type f  -exec basename '{}' ';' | xargs printf -- 'PATH_DIR2/%s\n' | xargs rm
```

Explanations :

1. List all filenames in PATH_DIR1

> find PATH_DIR1 -type f  -exec basename '{}' ';'

2. Filter the previous listing with the existing files in PATH_DIR2 (find the intersect data)

> xargs printf -- 'PATH_DIR2/%s\n'

3. Execute the remove action to the filtered result

> xargs rm

Comment: Is there any advantage to this approach over the others? Also, can you add an explanation of the commands?